# how give input in Edittext removing one character from hint at a time

Tags: android

**>      I have a Edit Text with hint 0.00

> ```
> Now i want to input text  
> If i press 5 it should appear 0.05  
> next if i press 4 it should come like 0.54**
> ```

Comment: And what if i am pressing 2(after pressing 5 and 4)
What should be the result.??

Comment: than it should appear as 2.54

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct answer for my requirement

```
public static void decimalFormat(final EditText editText) {

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        String before = "";

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            before = s.toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (!before.equalsIgnoreCase(s.toString())
                    && !TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim())) {
                before = s.toString();
                String tvStr = s.toString();
                if (tvStr.contains("-") || tvStr.equals(".")) {
                    editText.setText("");
                }

                if (!tvStr.equals("") && !tvStr.equals(".")) {
                    String cleanString = getFormatedNumber(tvStr, 2);
                    editText.setText(cleanString);
                    try {
                        editText.setSelection(cleanString.length());

                        return;
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        editText.setSelection(cleanString.length() - 1);
                        return;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    });
}
```

public static String getFormatedNumber(String text, int decimalPoint) {

```
      String cleanString = text.replaceAll("[,.|\\s]", "");
      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cleanString)) {
       return "0.00";
      }

      NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

      double number = Double.parseDouble(cleanString) / (long) Math.pow(10.0, decimalPoint);
      return formatter.format(number).toString();
     }
```